# How do I get a specific part of a file path from a server name?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm going to try to articulate this the best that I can.

I have a block of JSP code that requests a file outside the war file.

```
  Reader reader = new FileReader("/path/to/"+env+"/this/file.html");
```

There will be several testing environments that will test this code.  4 to be exact.

```
"/path/to/"+env1+"/this/file.html"
"/path/to/"+env2+"/this/file.html"
"/path/to/"+env3+"/this/file.html"
"/path/to/"+env4+"/this/file.html"
```

I started off with:

```
    <% String env=" ";


>%
```

Here is where I'm stuck.  I know I have to call a getServerName() but I'm frozen. Can't seem to figure a way to select that part of the path.  I have searched but I guess I'm not describing it correctly.

Comment: *I have a block of JSP code that requests a file outside the war file.* You should re-consider that. Servlet code should usually not access the file system!

Answer (score 0):

Does the [HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) helps you further?

Comment: I'll give it a shot of course.  Again, I'm trying to select a specific part of the URI  (env1, env2, env3, env4), then assign it to env.

Answer (score 0):

To get the physical location of your servlet, call the following code :

```
String realPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

This will return the path of your web application. Then, you can append to it the HTML file path.